# PHP: how to populate html form fields with query results using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to populate a form with values after performing a simple search but when I run the script, I either get "undefined" or a blank response when I do alert(data);.

**search.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'config/config.php';
include_once 'config/connect.php';
$conn = dbconn();

if(isset($_POST['btn-search']))
{
    $sub_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$sub_id."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    $found = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $found[] = array(
            'name' => $row['full_name'],
            'init_date' => $row['init_date'],
            'position' => $row['position'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
        );
        echo json_encode($found);
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**script**

```
<script>
/*
simple validation script
*/

$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#register-submit-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     /* validation */
     $("#register-form").validate({
      rules:
      {
            user_id: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            },
       },
       messages:
       {
            cedulaid:{
                      required: "The user ID is required",
                      minlength: "The user ID should be no less than 5 characeters long.",
                     },
       },
       submitHandler: submitForm
       });  
       /* validation */

       /* get data */
       function submitForm()
       {        
            var data = $("#details-form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'search.php',
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#detailsmsg").fadeOut();
                $("#btn-search").html('<img src="include/btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Looking...');
                $('#btn-search').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            success :  function(data)
               {
               alert(data);
                        $("#detailsmsg").fadeIn(1000, function(){                       
                        $("#detailsmsg").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
                        $('#btn-search').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $("#btn-search").html('Search again?');
                        $('#register-submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $("#detailsmsg").html("<span>Data Found</span>");

                        });
                        $("#name").val(data.name); // not sure how to do this part. this is probably very wrong but still not getting anything on the alert.
                        $("#init_date").val(data.init_date);
                        $("#position").val(data.position);
                        $("#email").val(data.email);
              }
            });
                return false;
        }
       /* get data */
});
</script>
```

I have the alert(data) at the top of the success function because I want to see what I would get in return but it comes back blank. If I do alert(data[0]) I get "undefined" message.

the console POST returns this:

```
name=&init_date=&position=&email=
```

There are probably many mistakes in the script and I'm open to any feedback and help I can get. Let me know if any other details are needed.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can try to put  echo json_encode($found); out off loop from search.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for getting single output, you only need a $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res); not loop..it will return single parameter output..

```
Search.php

<?php
include_once 'config/config.php';
include_once 'config/connect.php';
$conn = dbconn();

if(isset($_POST['btn-search']))
{
    $sub_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$sub_id."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    $found = array();

        $found[] = array(
            'name' => $row['full_name'],
            'init_date' => $row['init_date'],
            'position' => $row['position'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
        );
        echo json_encode($found);

}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

try it once..may be it will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Kamlesh Gupta. your suggestion made some progress. I got a result this time but I'm getting all nulled values. [{"name":null,"init_date":null,"position":null,"email":null}]. if I query the database with the sample user_id I'm testing this with, I get the results I'm looking for so I don't think it has anything to do with the query. any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I manned to get the values into the array by changing modifying the data: data, in the ajax call to data: data : {user_id: $('#user_id').val()}, and the POST in the php script from if(isset($_POST['btn-search'])) to if(isset($_POST['user_id'])). now how do I get the values into the input fields?

Comment: Ok. I got it to work. I was using JSON.stringify(data) and I was getting the array results but I removed dataType: 'json', and did result = jQuery.parseJSON(data); and now I can use result.user_id to get the value from the array. so $("#user_id").val(result.user_id); now works.

Answer (score 1):

By just quickly looking at the PHP code it returns nested arrays:

```
[
    [
        'name' => 'whatever',
        'init_date' => 'date',
        ...
    ]
]
```

This happens because you first define `$found = array();` and then append more arrays to it with `$found[] = array(...)`.

The javascript part however tries to access just `data.name` which doesn't exist. Maybe `data[0].name` should exist assuming there's at least one record in the database.

Did you want to iterate `data` as an array instead?

But maybe the problem lies in the PHP part where you call `mysqli_fetch_array()` twice and therefore override `$row` variable and skip the first result found:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

$found = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
...
```

Last thing I see is that you probably want to call `echo json_encode($found);` after the `while` loop when you've collected all search results. By the way, this also produces invalid JSON.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I removed the loop as suggested by Kamlesh Gupta and it made some progress. I don't necessarily need to iterate data as an array but I considered it was a good approach. I don't know how to pass the value of a php variable to fill out the expected field. if I do a regular variable like $user_id = $row['user_id']; how can I load the value into the form?